# Unable to Create New Folders on External Drives (Access Denied)

Tags: windows, external-hard-drive

Since May of 2020 last year, I've been having a problem on my laptop in which I can't copy any files to external drives (flash drives and WD hard drives). Everywhere online it says to go to "Properties" and "Security" but my flash drive does not have that because it is FAT32 which does not support security. I have also checked the Group Policy (Windows Professional) and I have confirmed that anything pertaining to disabling external storage access is not configured or is disabled. This also happened, more recently, to another laptop I had. Before, I used it to write to drives because my computer couldn't. However, one day I think I took the USB drive out without ejecting, and the problem arose on that computer too (running the same OS). I've mostly just ignored the problem but now my computer only has 10MB of space left and I need to use the external flash drive to move some of my files too. Note that my computer runs Symantec Endpoint Protection (and so did the other laptop) but I have disabled it (at least I think, I don't see it in the system tray anymore) by modifying the registry to stop it from starting at my computer's startup. Here is what the error looks like: [Destination Folder Access Denied](https://i.stack.imgur.com/po6uN.png)

Note that this happens regardless of the external drive used, and that there is no physical switch on either devices that disables writing. I can write just fine using other devices. I do not think this is a permissions issue because it is FAT32. Note that takeown / chkdsk all fail (even in elevated / administrator mode) on the external drive with the error "Access Denied." My drives have essentially become read-only on this machine.

Thank you for reading this and your help is appreciated.

Comment: `Symantec Endpoint Protection` suggests this machine is connected to an AD domain is that the case?

Comment: I went to cmd and typed "set user" and looked at USERDNSDOMAIN and USERDOMAIN which show that it is indeed connected to a domain. This used to be my mom's computer, when she upgraded, I got the old one.

Comment: [Try not using a domain user account or more importantly disconnect the machine from the domain that no longer exists.](https://serverfault.com/questions/412263/command-to-remove-computer-from-non-existant-domain)

Comment: Thanks for the response, I will try this. However, will I still be able to login to my computer? I'm pretty sure the domain still exists, and when I login I think I use a domain account. I'm not sure if leaving the domain will still allow me to log in to my PC.

Comment: It would be unusual for a domain to be accessible outside of its intranet, if it is accessible, then you cannot solve this problem since you don’t have administrator access on the machine.  You said this was an “old machine” connected to a AD domain, that tells me it can be safely removed from the domain, and local user accounts can be used instead.  Once removed from the domain, the user on that domain, will obviously be inaccessible. However, your looking to solve a problem, that’s solved by removing a machine that should not be connected to a domain

Comment: I see. I don't think I have a local user account. I think I will try creating a new local account so I don't lose access when I disconnect from the domain.

Answer (score 0):

1. remove "HP device manager" or "HP device access manager". it has this particular bad habit to deny access
2. if that's not it, can you try on command prompt:

- diskpart
- list disk
- select disk n (where n is the number of your disk)
- attributes disk
- if it says read only, then enter: attributes disk clear readonly

3. unlikely, but do the drives have any physical switch? if yes, change their position as this could be what is making them read-only
4. another suggestion if those weren't it - check group policy settings:

- Computer Configuration\Administrative Templates\System\Removable Storage Access
- User Configuration\Administrative Templates\System\Removable Storage Access

Comment: Thank you for the response. The laptop is a Dell device and the only HP programs I have are for my HP laserjet printer. I went to the start menu, and in search I typed "HP device manager"and "HP device access manager" and nothing showed up.  HP ePrint and HP LaserJet Guide are the only two HP programs on my PC. I did complete your diskpart instructions on both disks (external and internal) both which read "No" for read only. Group policy for both configurations shows disabled / not configured which according to the side bar means users should have write access.

Comment: Does it work in Safe mode? If yes, one of the startup programs/services is blocking your access.

Comment: Hello CrazyEyesDave, I just tried in Safe mode, unfortunately the problem persists.